# ¿Por qué no me toma los datos de la insertados?

Tags: html, python, flask

Estoy tratando de insertar varios datos en una tabla a otra, pero no me está tomando los datos desde el HTML, he intentado varias formas, también intenté tomar el número como una variable e insertarlo directo, pero no me funcionó.

Esto es lo que estoy intentando hacer, que de 2 tablas me traiga un valor y los inserte en una tabla llamada **cantidad**, que tiene 2 `id` y solo 3 campos, donde está el `id` del conteo y el `id` del producto, pero cuando intento insertar los datos, la página sólo se recarga.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Python:

```
@app.route('/new', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def new():
    #selecion de proveedores: coneccion a Db, Quey, diccionario, cerrar Db, imprimir lista de diccionario

    g.con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=AUS_COMPUTO02\SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE=DBWEBSERVICE; Trusted_Connection = yes;')
    cur = g.con.execute("SELECT *FROM PROVEEDOR")
    prov =[dict(ID=row[0],DESCRIPCION=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.con.close()
    #content = prov
    ########################################################################################################################################
    #sleccion desde proveedores: entrada, conectar a DB, Query, diccionario con bucle,
    #request.args.get('sea')
    pv = request.args.get('prove')
    g.con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=AUS_COMPUTO02\SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE=DBWEBSERVICE; Trusted_Connection = yes;')
    cur = g.con.execute("SELECT p.id, p.codigo, p.descripcion FROM dbo.Productos p where p.idProveedor = (?) ", (pv))
    cnt = [dict(id=row[0],codigo=row[1],descripcion=row[2]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    #ids = [dict(id=row[0]) for row in cur.fetchall()] 
    cur.commit()

    g.con.close()

    g.con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=AUS_COMPUTO02\SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE=DBWEBSERVICE; Trusted_Connection = yes;')
    cur = g.con.execute("SELECT Ident_current('Conteo')")
    ind = [dict(Conteo=row[0]) for row in cur.fetchall()]

    g.con.close()

    #######################################################################################################################################

    ########################################################################################################################################
    # insert valores en las tablas DETALLE DE CONTEO, TOMAR VALORES  de va riables getdate y proveedor
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:

            dcont = request.form['dcont']
            ids = request.form['ids']
            cn   = request.form['cn']



            with sql.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=AUS_COMPUTO02\SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE=WEBSERVICE; Trusted_Connection = yes;") as con:
                    cur = con.cursor()
                    cur = con.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.DETALLECONTEO  VALUES (?,?,?)", (dcont,ids,cn))               

                    cur.commit()
                    msg = "Successfully added"
                    print(cur)
                    print(dcont,ids,cn)


        except:
            con.rollback()
            msg = "error inserte la operacion nuevamente"


        finally: 
            # con.close()
            return render_template ('result.html')

    return render_template('new.html', prov=prov, cnt=cnt, ind=ind )


@app.route('/consult',methods=['GET','POST'])
def consult():
    #selecion de proveedores: coneccion a Db, Quey, diccionario, cerrar Db, imprimir lista de diccionario

    g.con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=AUS_COMPUTO02\SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE=DBWEBSERVICE; Trusted_Connection = yes;')
    cur = g.con.execute("SELECT *FROM PROVEEDOR")
    prov =[dict(ID=row[0],DESCRIPCION=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.con.close()
    print(prov)

    pr = request.args.get('pr')
    g.con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=AUS_COMPUTO02\SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE=DBWEBSERVICE; Trusted_Connection = yes;')
    cur = g.con.execute("SELECT p.id, p.codigo, p.descripcion FROM dbo.Productos p where p.idProveedor = (?) ", (pr))
    cnt = [dict(id=row[0],codigo=row[1],descripcion=row[2]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    cur.commit()
    print(cnt)

    print(pr)
    g.con.close()

    return render_template('consult.html', prov=prov, cnt=cnt  )







if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HMTL:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" class="form-control" class="w-auto p-3">
        <table class="table" class="form-control">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Descipcion</th>
                    <th acope="col">Cantidad</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for c in cnt %}
                  <tr>
                    <td >{{ c.codigo }}</td>
                     <td>{{ c.descripcion }}</td>

                     <td > <input name='cn' type="number" class="form-control"></td>

                     <td><select name='dcont'>
                       {% for i in ind %}
                       <option value=" {{i.Conteo}}"> {{i.Conteo}} </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                    </td>
                     <td> <select name='ids'>
                       <option value="{{c.id}}"> {{c.id}} </option>
                     </select>
                    </td>

                  {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
                </tbody>
              </table>              
              <input class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" ><br>

              </form>
```

Comment: Imagino que podras iterar sobre el objeto request.form o bien necesitaras IDs unicos para cada campo que quieres obtener.

Comment: ya los tengo si te fijas en los cosgigos los id estan pero no me esta tomando los datos, cuando inserto y envio el formulario este no se ejecuta

Comment: Ah ya vi. Te faltan el method y el action en el form. Method deberia ser POST, y action la url que definiste como ruta en el codigo python. Si con eso no te funciona, muestra el codigo completo de tu aplicacion flask (menos las rutas que no sean relevantes a esta pregunta)

Comment: ya prove proniendo el metodo post en el html y aun sigue sin tomar los datos

Comment: Probaste a poner el action? Asegurate de actualizar tu codigo donde se vea el method y action de tu <form> porque tal y como lo tienes ahora, el form no hace nada.

Comment: puse la accion y el post y nada sigue sin tomarme los datos,   <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"  action=" {{ url_for('new') }} " method='POST'> se supone que con esto deveria funcionar

Comment: Pon el resto de tu codigo python entonces.

Comment: intenta algo como `<input name='cn[{{c.id}}]' type="number" class="form-control">` resulta que el input se llama igual en toda la tabla

Comment: no por que en cn seria donde tomaria la cantidad. tiene c.id seria el id de cada uno de los elementos que estan en la tabla